# How do I specify Discount codes when using the RailShopRQ to query Amtrak availability?

Tags: sabre

I'm struggling to find how to add Discount Codes to a RailShopRQ targeting Amtrak.

I've seen Amtraks own site applying the discounts but when searching fo rthe same availability using Sabre's RailShopRQ I've been unable to secure the lower fares.

I've tried adding DiscountTypes to the Discounts attribute on the PassengerType in RailShopRQOffersSearchCriteria. I've also tried adding it to the Discounts attribute directly on the RailShopRQOffersSearchCriteria but neither of them bring back any reduced fares.

Is this the correct way to request discounted fares or do I need to make a separate call with a different ResponseType? Once I have the discounted fares do I then need to provide the discount codes during the RailManageBookingRQ and RailManageTicketRQ to ensure the correct Fare is sold?

Comment: I don't have an example, so it would be good to have a discount code example and for which route.

Comment: We are using the promocode V223. This should be valid on the 686 Downeaster train between Portland (POR) and Boston North (BON) leaving at 2:35pm. Using the Amtrak site this gives a 25% discount on the Value fare pricing it at $15 one way. When we apply this through the RailShopRQ the fare shows as $20

Comment: This is an example request

Comment: <RailShopRQ SearchType="AVAIL">
<OffersSearchCriteria>
<AvailQueryCriteria MaxConnections="2" JourneyDirection="Outbound">
...
</AvailQueryCriteria>
<PassengerTypes>
 <PassengerType Name="Vernon Bear" Code="F" Quantity="1">
  <Discounts>
   <Discount Code="V223" Quantity="1"/>
  </Discounts>
 </PassengerType>
</PassengerTypes>

<Discounts>
 <Discount Code="V223" Quantity="1"/>
</Discounts>

</OffersSearchCriteria>
</RailShopRQ>

Comment: From what I was able to find, you should add the discount with its name, something like this: <Discount Code="V223" Name="CorpDiscountNmbr"/>

Comment: Hi Wisdoom, thanks for the reply. We've tried your suggestion with no luck. Does the name we use matter or is there a list of accepted discount types that we can choose from?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the problem or if it has to be enabled somehow by the vendor. I recommend you to get in touch with the helpdesk so they can escalate the question if necessary (webservices.support@sabre.com).
You may also try the Sabre Rail app in Sabre Red Workspace to see if it actually works there.